# Cannot delete file after upload by multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I use multer package to upload file. And I use sharp to resize and copy many file, so then I can not delete the first upload file.

Here is my code

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: 'upload/'});

app.route('/uploadIcon')
        .post(upload.single('file'), uploadfunction);


function uploadfunction(req, res) {
    var dir = './app/controllers/configs/' + req.body.domain;
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir + '/icon.iconset')) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir + '/icon.iconset');
    }
    var dir_icon = dir + '/icon.iconset/';

    var file = dir + '/icon.iconset/' + 'default.png';

    fs.rename(req.file.path, file, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(500);
        } else {
            resizeandcopy(file, dir_icon);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is function resizeandcopy.

```
function resizeandcopy(file, dir) {
    sharp(file)
            .resize(16, 16)
            .toFile(dir + 'icon_16x16.png', function (err) {
            });


}
```

I think memory isn't purged after image upload and process or, need to close event after dealing with files. But I don't know how to fix this.
Sb can help me?

Comment: what do you get when log `req.file.path`

Comment: I solved it. Just use `sharp.cache(false);`

Comment: Nice one, I like it